# How can I get the information that the start time is the end time in the next change according to the status of a data in the table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a data set with continuous data coming from the table. I have a column with [Status] in it. I'm trying to calculate the time in between by taking the date from the row with [Status] = 0 and taking the time as "EndTime" from the first row with [Status] > 0 as "StartTime". But I couldn't do the query. My table is as below:

| LINE | TIMESTAMP | CL_Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-01-03 11:25:33.917 | FILM | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-01-03 11:20:33.917 | FILM | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-01-03 11:15:33.910 | FILM | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-01-03 11:10:33.903 | FILM | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-01-03 11:05:33.900 | FILM | 0 |

The table I'm trying to make is

| LINE | CL_Name | StartTime | EndTime | TotalTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | FILM | 2023-01-03 11:05:33.900 | 2023-01-03 11:25:33.917 | 20Min |

Here, the algorithm is to find the date data as "[Status]" = 0, take the date data as "StartTime" and then find the first "[Status]" = 1, take the date data and take that data as "EndTime" and try to find the time difference between the two.

I wrote my sql query as follows, but I was not completely successful.

```
  SELECT [LINE], [CL_Name], StartTime, EndTime, 
      DATEDIFF(second, startTime, endTime) as TotalTime
 FROM ( select [LINE], [CL_Name], [TIMESTAMP], [Status],
    Min(case when [Status] > 0 then [TIMESTAMP] end) as EndTime,
    Min(case when [Status] = 0 then [TIMESTAMP] end) as StartTime
  from [dbo].[CL]
  group by [LINE], [CL_Name], [_VALUE], [TIMESTAMP], [Status]) as tt
  where StartTime IS NOT NULL and EndTime IS NOT NULL
  Order by [TIMESTAMP] desc
```

| LINE | CL_Name | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | FILM | NULL | 2023-01-03 11:25:33.917 |
| 2 | FILM | NULL | 2023-01-03 11:20:33.917 |
| 2 | FILM | 2023-01-03 11:15:33.910 | NULL |
| 2 | FILM | 2023-01-03 11:10:33.903 | NULL |
| 2 | FILM | 2023-01-03 11:05:33.900 | NULL |

The output I wanted

| LINE | CL_Name | StartTime | EndTime | TotalTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | FILM | 2023-01-03 11:05:33.900 | 2023-01-03 11:25:33.917 | 20Min |

Comment: Could a given line ever have more than a single start/end pair?

Comment: T-SQL is used by several (R)DBMS products; which are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, multiple lines can be

Comment: @Larnu This query in T-SQL MS SQL server

Comment: Is it `taking the date from the row with [Status] = 0 and taking the time as "EndTime"` OR `the date data as "[Status]" = 0, take the date data as "StartTime"` ?

Comment: @Squirrel I'm trying to take the data with [Status] = 0 as "StartTime" and then the data with [Status] > 0 as "EndTime" .

Comment: Is it possible to have a LINE without status=0, or a LINE begins with a status=1? or it always starts with 0 then changes to 1 and so on.

Comment: `find the first "[Status]" = 1, take the date data and take that data as "EndTime"`  Isn't the time should be `2023-01-03 11:20:33.917` ? But your required result shows `2023-01-03 11:25:33.917`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, explanation within query comments:

```
/* check if the status is changed over the increasing time,
   and set a value of 1 whenever a change is occur
*/
WITH Check_Changes AS
(
  SELECT *,
    IIF(Status <> LAG(Status, 1, Status) OVER (PARTITION BY LINE, CL_NAME ORDER BY TIMESTAMP), 1 , 0) flag
  FROM CL
),
/* create groups using a running sum of the calculated flag in
   the previous CTE. This will give the same number for the 
   consecutive similar status values i.e. for (0000,11,000,11) it 
   will be (0000,11,222,33)
*/
Craete_Groups AS
(
  SELECT *, 
    SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY LINE, CL_NAME ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) +
    CASE WHEN SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY LINE, CL_NAME ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) % 2 = Status
    THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS grp
FROM Check_Changes
/*  CASE WHEN SUM(flag) OVER ... is to check if the status begins with a 0 value. 
    In the typical case, the even groups will be within status=0 and the odd groups will be within status=1.
    This will add 1 to the group value if the status does not start with 0 i.e. for status = (1111,000,111)
    it will be (1111,222,333) instead of (0000,111,222)
*/
)
/* now you can connect every two consecutive groups together by using grp/2
i.e. groups (0000,11,222,33) will be (0000,00,111,11)
*/
SELECT LINE, CL_Name,
       MIN(CASE WHEN Status = 0 THEN TIMESTAMP END) StartTime, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN TIMESTAMP END) EndTime, 
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
                MIN(CASE WHEN Status = 0  THEN TIMESTAMP END), 
                MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 1  THEN TIMESTAMP END)
               ) TotalTime
FROM Craete_Groups
GROUP BY LINE, CL_Name, grp/2
ORDER BY LINE, CL_Name, MIN(TIMESTAMP)
```

[See a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zekNu0xp) on an extended data sample.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked for me and also thank you for your detailed explanations, you summarized it well.